# Why does match.call not work when the original call is wrapped in a function?

Tags: r, recursion, arguments

I want to pass down function arguments to recursively call a function within itself (usually with a break condition, of course).

I learnt that `match.call` should work to capture all arguments, and it works - until I wrap the original call in another function.

```
inner <- function(my_arg) {
    message(my_arg)
    do.call("inner", as.list(match.call()[-1]))
}

# this yields an error ... (unexpected)
outer <- function() {
    mydata <- data.frame(1)
    inner(mydata)
}
outer()

# ... while this yields an infinite loop (expected)
mydata <- data.frame(1)
inner(mydata)
```

This outputs:

```
1
Error in is.data.frame(my_arg) : object 'mydata' not found
```

Why is that? Is this intended? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It's really difficult to explain the error because it results from the interaction of `do.call`, `match.call` and recursion. The problem results from when the promises of the nested calls `inner(my_arg = mydata)` are forced. When `message` is called, R searches the function scope and, in case the object is not found, the enclosing environments. This appears to fail when a promise in the nested calls hasn't been forced (due to your `do.call("inner", as.list(match.call()[-1]))` construct).

```
> traceback()
5: message(my_arg) at #2
4: inner(my_arg = mydata)
3: do.call("inner", as.list(match.call()[-1])) at #4
2: inner(mydata) at #4
1: outer()
```

I suggest you study the [language definition, e.g. Section 4.3.3](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Argument-evaluation).

Also, why do you need `match.call` here? Just use `inner(my_arg)` instead of that `do.call` with `match.call` construct. That immediately forces the promise and everything works fine.

Comment: Why do I need `match.call`? Because my function has a bunch of arguments that I would prefer not to repeat in the code.

Comment: Then use `...` such as `inner <- function(...) {message(..1); inner(...)}`. `...` can be mixed with named arguments if necessary (e.g., because you modify an argument): `inner <- function(arg, ...) { message(arg); inner(arg, ...)}`.

Comment: Also, it's usually best to avoid recursion in R. It's usually not efficient.

Comment: Well, I should not have said "recursion" in the first place. I have an `f(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, etc.)` from which I would like to call, if `e != 0`, `f(a, b, c, d, 0, f, g, h, etc.)`. That's about it.

Comment: Well, no reason for using `match.call` then.

Comment: Oh sure there is. Maintainability of code, for example: one may want to be able to add arguments in a single place. Readability of code is another one: the reader of the code should not need to double-check that all but one argument is unchanged - the code should explicitly state that. Etc etc.

Comment: `match.call` does not solve this. Its actual purpose is orthogonal to your goals. I have already indicated that there are better ways of achieving your actual goals.

Comment: "I have already indicated that there are better ways" - I guess you mean the ellipsis method? This one has other downsides, such as convoluted parameter processing, limited linting (checking for accepted parameters), etc. Clearly, `named_param` reads better than `..1`. And all these numerous parameters *are* used in the code, it's not that they are *only* passed down (in which case I might agree with you).

Comment: Well, good luck. Just don't use `match.call` here if you want to avoid surprising bugs. If you have further questions, best to ask them as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of scoping. Hopefully this modification of your two functions will give a clear picture of what's going on (with no infinite loops!), and how to fix it.

```
inner <- function(my_arg)
{
  mc <- match.call()
  cat("Call to inner:\n")
  print(mc)
  cat("\nSymbol to be evaluated within \"inner\":\n")
  print(as.list(mc)$my_arg)
  cat("\nSymbol evaluated in scope of \"inner\":\n")
  tryCatch(print(eval(as.list(mc)$my_arg)),
           error = function(e) cat("**Error** - symbol not found\n"))
  cat("\nSymbol evaluated in parent frame of \"inner\":\n")
  tryCatch(print(eval(as.list(mc)$my_arg, envir = parent.frame())),
           error = function(e) cat("**Error** - symbol not found\n"))
}

outer <- function()
{
  my_data <- "outer test string"
  inner(my_data)
}
```

Which we can test as follows:

```
inner("inner test string")
#> Call to inner:
#> inner(my_arg = "inner test string")
#> 
#> Symbol to be evaluated within "inner":
#> [1] "inner test string"
#> 
#> Symbol evaluated in scope of "inner":
#> [1] "inner test string"
#> 
#> Symbol evaluated in parent frame of "inner":
#> [1] "inner test string"

outer()
#> Call to inner:
#> inner(my_arg = my_data)
#> 
#> Symbol to be evaluated within "inner":
#> my_data
#> 
#> Symbol evaluated in scope of "inner":
#> **Error** - symbol not found
#> 
#> Symbol evaluated in parent frame of "inner":
#> [1] "outer test string"
```